# Scroll bottom chat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, scroll

I'm trying to scroll the end of the div when I open the ng-show chat window, but it only works on the second click. I've tried it in many ways but I'm not getting it to make the first click work already.

HTML CHAT:

```
<div class="chat">
    <div class="" ng-show="chatdis">
        <div class="chat-header vertical-center clearfix">
           <img ng-src="user/pix.php/{{ctrl.idchat}}/f1.jpg" class="imgperfil img-circle" alt="avatar" ng-class="{'online': ctrl.useronline, 'offline': !ctrl.useronline}"/>
           <div class="chat-about">
               <div class="chat-with">{{ctrl.namechat}}</div>
           </div>
           <div class="close pull-right" style="opacity: 0.6;" ng-click="ctrl.fecharconversa()">
               <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;font-size: 16px;position: absolute;top: 6px;right: 8px;color: #797979;"></i>
           </div>
        </div> <!-- end chat-header -->

        <div class="chat-history">
           <ul style="margin: 0;padding: 0;">
              <li ng-id="message-{{obj.id}}" class="clearfix" ng-repeat="obj in ctrl.mensagens | orderBy:'-'">
                 <div class="message" ng-class="{'other-message': obj.useridto == <?php echo $USER->id ?>, 'my-message float-right': obj.useridto != <?php echo $USER->id ?>}">
                    <p ng-bind-html="obj.smallmessage"></p>
                    <span class="tail-container"></span>
                    <span class="tail-container highlight"></span>
                 </div>

                 <div class="message-data" ng-class="{'align-right': obj.useridto != <?php echo $USER->id ?>}">
                    <span class="message-data-time" ng-class="{'text-right': obj.useridto != <?php echo $USER->id ?>}" ng-if="obj.useridto != <?php echo $USER->id ?>">
                       {{obj.firstname}} {{obj.lastname}} - {{obj.timecreated | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="message-data-time" ng-if="obj.useridto == <?php echo $USER->id ?>">
                       {{obj.timecreated | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}} - {{obj.firstname}} {{obj.lastname}}
                    </span>
                 </div>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div> <!-- end chat-history -->

        <div class="chat-message clearfix">
            <textarea name="message-to-send" ng-model="message" id="message-to-send" placeholder ="Escreva sua mensagem" rows="2"></textarea>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.inseremensagem(ctrl.idchat, message, ctrl.namechat, ctrl.useronline)">Enviar</button>
        </div> <!-- end chat-message -->
     </div>
  </div> <!-- end chat -->
```

CONTROLLER FUNCTION:

```
self.abrirconversa = function(useridfrom, name, useronline){
    $rootScope.chatdis = true;

    chatservice.conversachat(useridfrom).then(function(d) {
        self.mensagens = d;

        for(var i = 0; i < self.mensagens.length; i++){
            //converte datas em Javascript
            if(self.mensagens[i].timecreated != null && self.mensagens[i].timecreated != '12/31/1969 21:00'){
                self.mensagens[i].timecreated = new Date(self.mensagens[i].timecreated);
            }
        }

        self.idchat = useridfrom;
        self.namechat = name;
        self.useronline = useronline;

        $('.chat-history').animate({scrollTop: $('.chat-history')[0].scrollHeight}, 0);

    }, function(errResponse){
        console.error('Error while fetching Currencies');
    });
};
```

The controller function, I call it when I click on a list of people in the side menu. Can someone help me? :D

Comment: Ditch the Jquery and look at $anchorScroll. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: how else would you do to anchor the last chat message? I do not think it's the best option

Comment: Basically assign it an id, keep track of the last id issued in your controller and use $anchorScroll to scroll to it.